# CSS Keyframe Animation pauses in between

Tags: html, css, animation

### Solution:

As proposed from user @Kosh changing

```
animation-timing-function: linear;
```

fixed the problem.

### Question:

I´m trying to make a coinflip like animation using CSS Keyframes.

```
@keyframes spin-head {
  0% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.6) rotateX(1080deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(2160deg);
  }
}


.coin {
    animation: spin-head 3s forwards
}
```

However as seen in the gif, the coin makes a small pause after reaching 50% before it starts the second part of the animation.
Does anyone know why this occurs?[image: GIF Animation of the Coinflip]

Comment: This is because `animation-timing-function` default value is `ease`. You have to set it `linear` probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `animation-timimg-function: linear;` will get rid of this behavior.